# How to tell LinqToSQL to use outer join when multiple keys?

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have three tables: `tblApplications`, `tblInterviews` and `tblDocuments` (simplified).

```sql
create table tblApplications(
    aplID int not null, --primary key
    aplName varchar(max) not null
)
create table tblInterviews(
    intApl int not null, --primary key & foreign key (tblApplications)
    intID int not null, --primary key
    intDate date not null
)
create table tblDocuments(
    docID int not null, --primary key
    docApl int not null, --foreign key (tblApplications & tblInterviews)
    docInt int null, --foreign key (tblInterviews)
    docPath varchar(max) not null
)
```

As you can see, application is the 'top' entry, each interview has to reference an application.
And each document has to reference an application and may or may not reference an interview.

If I load this schema into the LinqToSQL designer and try to select the document, it only selects the ones that reference an interview as it uses an `inner join` to bind the interviews to it.

However it should use an `outer join` as (part of) the key (`docInt`) is nullable.

How can I tell LinqToSQL to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty` in your select clause

`DefaultIfEmpty() method  forces the inclusion of null child references where parents have no children. Note that this method of performing an outer join produces a flattened result.`

Here you have a vb.net syntax example:

```
Dim JoinedResult = _
    From t1 In Table1 _
    Group Join t2 In Table2 _
       On t1.key Equals t2.key _
       Into RightTableResults = Group _
    From t2 In RightTableResults.DefaultIfEmpty _
    Select t1.Prop1, _
       t2.Prop2
```

Check this link:

[Outer Join Sample](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/DefaultIfEmptyOperator.ashx)

Comment: Hmmm... Thank you. I actually try to select the other way around `apl.interviews.Any()` but as I added the interview to be included in the select `dlo.LoadWith(Function(d As Document) d.interview)`, any returns false.
If there is no other possibility I will remove the loadwith.

Comment: Its better you use the group join rather than Extensions